# Add large database file to iOS App bundle at compile time to avoid indexing?

Tags: ios, xcode, indexing, bundle, xcode4.4

I'm having a severe problem using the new versions of Xcode (4.4 & 4.5) in that, my project has a very large .sql database file stored in the project. This file cannot change, for many reasons... but it is +270Mb in size. This causes Xcode to hang on 'Indexing File...' and becomes completely slow and unresponsive to the point that I have to force quit the app, and cannot actually get any coding done. I have raised a bug report with Apple several times, but it is seemingly being ignored!

I do not want to disable Xcode indexing entirely as i find the code completion features incredibly useful.

My question is: Can i remove the database from the Xcode bundle resources, and then add it automatically at compile time?

Would appreciate any and all advice on how I could get round this problem.

Regards,
Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incase anyone comes across this problem of Xcode indexing a huge unwanted file... I fixed it by setting the file type in Xcode to an 'MP3 Audio file'...

Doesn't seem to have any effect on the function of the .sql file once it's in the App, but stops Xcode trying to index it.

If anyone has a better solution for this, i'd love to hear it!

Comment: Clever solution, been trying to sort this out for a long time.

Comment: Hi, I am also facing this issue. Can you tell me where should we set this file type in Xcode?

Comment: Sure, select the file from the navigation pane on the left, go to the file inspector (first icon at the top of the right hand pane), In the top section you will see 'Identity and Type', the type is a dropdown option box, from that select the file type you want!